# Change the display of Settings API (do_settings_sections)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, settings-api

I am working on a plugin which uses Wordpress Settings API. I notice that the functions `do_settings_sections` (and `do_settings_fields`) display the fields using TABLE. How do I change its formatting? (I want to use DIV instead of TABLE)

Comment: the settings api displays the fields the way you define in your callback function for each field.

Comment: My problem is not displaying the fields, but displaying the whole section. I want it to be in DIVs rather than it TABLE...

Comment: Whats your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no [hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters) to modify the output of [`do_settings_sections()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_settings_sections).

Hence the only option you have is to write custom versions of the functions [`do_settings_sections()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_settings_sections) and [`do_settings_fields()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_settings_fields). They are located in [/wp-admin/includes/template.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/includes/template.php), lines 1159-1174 and 1190-1207 (wordpress version 3.2.1), respectively (**do not** modify them there).

You *could* (not saying it is necessarily advisable, consider compatibility with future versions of wp) include something like this in your plugin:

```
function custom_do_settings_sections($page) {
    global $wp_settings_sections, $wp_settings_fields;

    if ( !isset($wp_settings_sections) || !isset($wp_settings_sections[$page]) )
        return;

    foreach( (array) $wp_settings_sections[$page] as $section ) {
        echo "<h3>{$section['title']}</h3>\n";
        call_user_func($section['callback'], $section);
        if ( !isset($wp_settings_fields) ||
             !isset($wp_settings_fields[$page]) ||
             !isset($wp_settings_fields[$page][$section['id']]) )
                continue;
        echo '<div class="settings-form-wrapper">';
        custom_do_settings_fields($page, $section['id']);
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

function custom_do_settings_fields($page, $section) {
    global $wp_settings_fields;

    if ( !isset($wp_settings_fields) ||
         !isset($wp_settings_fields[$page]) ||
         !isset($wp_settings_fields[$page][$section]) )
        return;

    foreach ( (array) $wp_settings_fields[$page][$section] as $field ) {
        echo '<div class="settings-form-row">';
        if ( !empty($field['args']['label_for']) )
            echo '<p><label for="' . $field['args']['label_for'] . '">' .
                $field['title'] . '</label><br />';
        else
            echo '<p>' . $field['title'] . '<br />';
        call_user_func($field['callback'], $field['args']);
        echo '</p></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This question was made 2 years ago and until now there is no hooks for this.

Thanks!